# Remove certain values in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
arr = [
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]
]
```

I want to remove the array that contains the element 4. Here it would remove 4,5,6. So it'd be arr = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9]];

I tried a `for` loop but I get 0. So I read this [Remove items from array with splice in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217333/remove-items-from-array-with-splice-in-for-loop)
but it didn't work. It removed the first number instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arr.filter(function(v) {
   return !v.includes(4);
});
```