# How to remove all item have isDone === true in array object Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, removeall

I want to remove all `element` have value `isDone === true` in array `list`. But i don't known remove all , I just remove each item one.

This is my code:

```
  clearCompleted: function (list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].isDone === true) {
        list.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  },
```

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: You can't modify the array you are looping over like that, there are a couple of things you can do to solve this issue. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217333/remove-items-from-array-with-splice-in-for-loop) answer for good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `while` or `do..while` loop, `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, `Array.prototype.find()` to avoid checking original array `.length` property

```js
let list = [{isDone:true}, {isDone:false}, {isDone:true}];

while (list.find(({isDone}) => isDone)) {
  list.splice(list.indexOf(list.find(({isDone}) => isDone)), 1)
}

console.log(list);
```

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: @TrầnHạnh The pattern can be composed using `for` loop `for (;list.find(({isDone}) => isDone);) {
  list.splice(list.indexOf(list.find(({isDone}) => isDone)), 1)
};
` which uses same amount of characters as `while` loop

Comment: Thanks for your help . Can you explain `({isDone}) => isDone)` for me? I don't understand it.

Comment: The syntax is [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).  Equivalent to `.find(function(object) {return object.isDone} )`

Comment: Thanks for your support. But I just learn ES5 javascript . :( . This practice just use ES5

Comment: @TrầnHạnh Not sure what you mean. The pattern can be composed without using arrow function, object destructuring or `.find()` `for (;list.filter(function(o){return o.isDone}).length;) {
  list.splice(list.indexOf(list.filter(function(o){return o.isDone})[0]), 1)
};`